# What is the purpose of Spring CharacterEncodingFilter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, filter

I'm working on an existing project in the configuration file I found this filter that I didn't understand the the purpose of this filter Spring CharacterEncodingFilter I read some documentation but still i didn't understand how it's work :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Any help Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think documentation is pretty clear: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html

"Servlet Filter that allows one to specify a character encoding for requests. This is useful because current browsers typically do not set a character encoding even if specified in the HTML page or form."